# Сколько запросов будет к базе данных (не учитывая подключение)

Tags: sql, pdo

```
$ids= "510112915907543042";
$pdo = connect_db()["pdo"];
$sql = "SELECT `ids`, `player_name`, `paladins_id` FROM `mee` WHERE `ids`=:ids";
$query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$answer = $query->execute(["ids" => $ids]); // 1 запрос
$answer = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // второй запрос к БД? или оно возьмет инфу из кэша первого запроса?
print_r($answer);
$pdo->connection = null;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один запрос. Функция fetch() преобразует результат, полученный в execute(), в нужный формат. В данном случае возвращается одна строка в виде ассоциированного массива.